# Send Email Using SQL Server With Check Before Certain Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query to send email using a stored procedure that will send the email when a certain date (closing  date in my case) is -1 or -2 from current date for some email.

I'm using the task scheduler, because I'm not just not running this query, but also another query; the scheduler runs from Monday to Friday.

For example, if the closing date is 11 October 2019 (Friday), the email will be sent on 09 October 2019 (Wednesday) and 10 October 2019 (Thursday).

The query below works fine if the closing date is Wednesday, Thursday or Friday; my question is, how to improve the query if the closing date is overlapping the weekend.

For example, if the closing date is 14 October (Monday), I want to send email on the 10 October (Thursday) and 11 October (Friday).

Or if closing date is 15 October (Tuesday), then the email will be sent on 11 October (Friday) and 12 October (Monday).

Here is my code

```
SELECT 
    pv.email, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(17), dbo.getPQDocSubmissionClosingDate(pqh.process_id), 113) AS pq_doc_closing_date
FROM 
    prequalification_vendor pv 
JOIN 
    prequalification_header pqh ON pv.prequalification_header_id = pqh.id
JOIN 
    proposal_header ph ON ph.tender_number = pqh.tender_number
WHERE 
    pv.pq_registration_status = 'Register' 
    AND pv.pq_docs_uploaded IS NULL  
    AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, dbo.getPQDocSubmissionClosingDate(pqh.process_id) , (SELECT CONVERT (DATE , GETDATE()))) = -2
         OR DATEDIFF(DAY, dbo.getPQDocSubmissionClosingDate(pqh.process_id) , (SELECT CONVERT (DATE , GETDATE()))) = -1)
```

`dbo.getPQDocSubmissionClosingDate(pqh.process_id)` --> this return datetime from another function

Comment: It seems to me you want to send the email 1 or 2 **business days** in advance. Search the internet for calendar table and use that instead of date functions. That way, the query will consider holidays as well as weekends.

Comment: calendar table ? is that query or what ?

Comment: It's literally what the name implies, it's a table that's a calendar. If you search, you're see plenty of resources on it.

Comment: Why have you tagged 2008 and 2012 here? One is now completely unsupported now, and the other only in extended support. The 2 are quite different in functionality as well; 2012 brough a lot of new stuff. What version are you *really* using?

Comment: i,m using 2008 R2 Version

Comment: @Heinrich, here is one [example of a calendar table](https://www.dbdelta.com/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions/) along with a script that loads common US holidays. You would use in in your query.

Comment: So neither of the versions you actually tagged. When tagging it's really important you tag the right product and version; otherwise you can (or will) end up with answers that don't work on your environment, or would be better using newer functionality you told is you don't have access to. Note that 2008R2 is also completely unsupported.